# Joomla one install file that installs component, modules and plugins

Tags: installation, joomla

I'm looking for a way to setup the XML install file for my component and for it to also install the plugins and modules that go along with it all in a single installation. Has anyone done this before, how can this be achieved?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try checking out http://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/ the basic editor installs the component and the affiliated plugin. Simply, it used the xml put the files in the correct places and uses an install.php script to finish. It does a lot of detailed things in some of the steps that you can ignore like all the component plugins etc.